# How to create videos on Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, video, video-editor

I want to create Text Videos on Ubuntu ie. I want to add some frames with just text in them into the video. But I also want to be able to add screengrab videos and music into them. Is there a tool on Ubuntu that can allow me to do so? Some basic animation effects would be wonderful. I dont really want to spend money so an opensource and free tool would be more useful.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

PS: I know how to make a screengrab video, I just want a software that allows making text videos and allows me to stitch multiple separate videos into one and also put music into it.

Comment: try openshot or KDEnlive if you have KDE desktop

Comment: Create a Powerpoint presentation and then screen record it

Comment: I use Openshot for this purpose.